# What happened to the inline help in Data Explorer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Just noticed the Data Explorer received a minor facelift, and the help icons in the schema panel which enumerated the different types(posttypes, posthistorytypes, postlinktypes, etc.) is now MIA. Is this a temporary change, or a new policy?

Answer (score 6):

[Fixed](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/27), pending a pull and redeploy.

I'm not sure how it got *broken* because the problem suggests it shouldn't have ever been working to begin with, but at least it's taken care of now.